# Mysql Database design structure

Tags: php, mysql, database

Which is a better db design when inserting records?

```
**Option 1.**
uid|itemid| qty | price | amount
1  |13| 2  |  100    |200

**Option 2.**
uid| itemid| qty | price | amount
1  |13| 1 | 100 | 100
2  |13| 1 | 100 | 100
```

In option 2 then retrieve rows via mysql query and calculate using id ...

Comment: The first one... this is exactly what MySQL is optimized to do.

Comment: Indeed the first, but miss off the "amount" if it's always quantity * price - unless you're going to do a lot is searching our ordering by about (in which case, leave itin and index it)

Comment: The 2nd table is flawed in that there is no Key. Tables without a Key are, for the most part, a red flag. Even adding a "LineNo" would be enough to qualify a Key. That being said, it feels like some context is missing. Please expand upon the types, relationships, and roles (to yourself, at least).

Comment: -1 For a very vague title. Update it to something relevant and I'll remove the down-vote. (E.g. "Table schema to store customer order?" or whatever is fitting.)

Comment: I've temporarily deleted my answer as I realize that "id" is ambiguous.  Is it an item, a sale or some other id? It would be good if you indicated what data this is being used to store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to retain the original price of each item ordered. What I'd do is go with option 1, then create another column in your table that holds a string that identifies each item in the order.

For example, if I were selling fruit, a banana could have `iZ` as a unique key. And an apple could have `6U` as a unique key. When a user places an order, these unique keys would be inserted into your new column. So when you see this column's data is `iZ6U` you'd know that the user ordered an apple and a banana.